# TYPO3: Symfony command with arguments AND dependency injection

Tags: php, symfony, typo3, extbase

I made a command in TYPO3 which has arguments and dependency injection (DI). 
As I understood in symfony DI is made with the __construct method. But there I also have to state the argument which I want to pass to the command. So how is it done correctly?

**Sources:**

- symfony how DI is made: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container
- Command controller in TYPO3 with symfony: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/BackendModules/CliScripts/Index.html?highlight=command%20controller#creating-a-new-symfony-command-in-your-extension

**Versions:** TYPO3 9.5.5, symfony 4.2.5

Say I want to pass one argument to the command AND inject the ObjectManager from TYPO3:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\Command;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

class SomeCommand extends Command 
{

    /**
     * Object Manager
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $cliParameter,
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager) 
    {
        $this->cliParameter = $cliParameter;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }
}
```

Then I call this with

```
bin/typo3 extension_name:someCommand foo
```

(where `foo` is the `$cliParameter`)

I get

`Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Cannot instantiate interface TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface`

So my question is: What did I wrong? What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: what 's the symfony version ?

Comment: have you tried to inject the ObjectManager instead of the ObjectManagerInterface? (yes, it is frowned upon to rely on a specific implementation, but maybe typo3 DI is not smart enough...?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony commands are unrelated to Extbase. So you cannot use DI [before TYPO3v10](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-89139-AddDependencyInjectionSupportForConsoleCommands.html). However, you can still get yourself an instance of the `ObjectManager` and then retrieve any object you need:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$exampleRepository = $objectManager->get(ExampleRepository::class);
```

If a class does not rely on Extbase or its DI, you can directly get an instance with `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` instead.

Notice that with TYPO3v10 or newer you can [use the native TYPO3 DI for commands](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-89139-AddDependencyInjectionSupportForConsoleCommands.html) instead.

Comment: Now ObjectManager::get is deprecated. I am searching for a way to inject my repository into the console command and I don't know how.

Comment: Yes I would like to know this too

Comment: someone found solution how to inject repository in to console command?

Comment: Starting from TYPO3 version 10.3, you can use DI in symfony commands by defining the command in the Services.yaml configuration as explained [here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-89139-AddDependencyInjectionSupportForConsoleCommands.html). Don't forget to flush the cache in the install tool after changing the Services.yaml file.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianFries, I've just incorporated this.

Comment: Everything you say is correct (regarding availability of DI in different contexts and T3 versions etc.), but IMHO one key aspect of OP's question is never answered: how DO you combine your own dynamic (ie not hardcoded in services.yaml) "arguments AND dependency injection"? I'm struggling with that in V11 while migrating a service class and the docs are not really clear about this (not to me at least...). But maybe this should go into a separate question. It just seemed to me that this combination was the actual issue at the heart of this question.

Comment: Yes, this is a different topic. Symfony command arguments are handled via an API, not via PHP "function arguments".